# Erro no such table. SqLite

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite3

Está dando esse erro, gostaria de saber se minha DAO está certa.

Erro:

```
08-06 14:19:53.304: E/SQLiteLog(16893): (1) no such table: proposta
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893): Error inserting validadebrinde=x validade=cd idusuario=1 brinde=c 
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: proposta (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO proposta(validadebrinde,validade,idusuario,brinde) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at br.com.android.controledevisitas.dao.PropostaDAO.cadastrar(PropostaDAO.java:43)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at br.com.android.controledevisitas.view.CadastrarPropostaActivity.cadastrarProposta(CadastrarPropostaActivity.java:122)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at br.com.android.controledevisitas.view.CadastrarPropostaActivity$2.onClick(CadastrarPropostaActivity.java:78)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17036)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-06 14:19:53.334: E/SQLiteDatabase(16893):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Minha DAO:

```
package br.com.android.controledevisitas.dao;

import br.com.android.controledevisitas.model.Proposta;
import br.com.android.controledevisitas.util.Dados;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class PropostaDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TABELA = "proposta";
    private static final Dados dados = new Dados();

    public PropostaDAO(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, dados.DATABASE, null, dados.VERSAO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "create table "
                + TABELA
                + "(id integer primary key, idusuario integer, validade text, brinde text, validadebrinde text);";
        db.execSQL(sql);

    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versaoAntiga, int versaoNova) {
        String sql = "drop table if exists " + TABELA;
        db.execSQL(sql);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Boolean cadastrar(Proposta p) {
        try {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("idusuario", 1);
            cv.put("validade", p.getValidade());
            cv.put("brinde", p.getBrinde());
            cv.put("validadebrinde", p.getValidadeBrinde());

            getWritableDatabase().insert(TABELA, null, cv);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("DAO", e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int getUltimoId() {
        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "select max(id) from " + TABELA, null);
        if (c.moveToNext()) {
            return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
        }
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: Está dando um erro na linha do `INSERT INTO proposta` mas no seu código você não nos mostrou nenhum insert. Seu erro com certeza é que você não está fazendo o create antes de fazer o insert.

Comment: Meu insert aqui getWritableDatabase().insert(TABELA, null, cv);
Tem um metodo cadastrar ai

Comment: Provavelmente seja esse o problema mesmo, mas porque ele n esta chamando o onCreate() quando eu instancio a classe DAO

Comment: Essa é uma boa pergunta. Tente debugar seu programa e ver se o método onCreate está sendo executado mesmo ou não. Será que não tá lançando alguma exceção ao tentar fazer o comando create?

Comment: Eu debuguei, ele não está sendo chamado, mas não entendo, porque eu instanciei a classe certo, era pra estar executando o onCreate(). Instanciei assim -> PropostaDAO pDao = new PropostaDAO(this);

Comment: Acho que me confundi no comentário anterior. Tente desinstalar o aplicativo do seu emulador ou celular, daí tente rodar novamente, pelo que eu li o onCreate() só é chamado na primeira vez que o app roda, que é quando seu bd é efetivamente criado. Ou se preferir, informe que existe uma nova versão de BD para forçar o método onUpgrade ser chamado

Comment: meisterx7, resolveu seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

- Verifica o metodo dados.DATABASE e dados.VERSAO não esta vazio ou null.

> ```
> public PropostaDAO(Context ctx)
> {
>         super(ctx, dados.DATABASE, null, dados.VERSAO);
> }
> ```

- Em seguida verifica como estas a inicializar o objeto PropostaDAO.

> ```
> PropostaDAO p=new PropostaDAO(context);
> p.cadastrar(proposta);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o SQLite não encontrou a tabela "proposta" verifique se o banco foi criado corretamente e se o nome é o mesmo no código e no SQLite.

Comment: como eu verifico se ele foi criado, pelo que estou vendo parece que ele não foi criado mesmo, queria saber porque

Comment: Qual IDE você está usando? Se for o Eclipse você pode tentar acessar o diretório data/data/nome_do_pacote. Neste caminho você tem acesso ao banco de dados. Para acessar pelo eclipse vá em Window > Show View > Other > Android > File Explorer. Caso a pasta esteja bloqueada tente acessar: http://www.programarandroid.com.br/2013/12/dica-como-acessar-pasta.html

Comment: Ela não foi criado, o onCreate da dao não foi chamado, porem eu instancie a classe certa, pelo menos acho que sim. PropostaDAO pDao = new PropostaDAO(this);

Comment: O ideal para as classes de criação do banco é rodar o toda vez que aplicação iniciar. Acredito que seja um padrão de todos criar uma classes que estenda **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper** sobrescrevendo os métodos onCreate e onUpdate. A chamada dos métodos é controlada pelo próprio Android. Neste caso ele irá executar uma unica vez. O construtor SQLiteOpenHelper recebe um inteiro que significa a versão do banco, quando esta versão muda o método onUpdate é executado. Verifique se a mesma foi implementada corretamente.